# Calculate mean of each row in a large list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list

I know this question has been asked before on this forum. But my data set is significantly large and I could not make any of the existing solutions work.

Here's a sample dataset.

```
list(structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), value = c(2, 
0, 2), value_2 = c(0, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), value = c(-1, 
0, 0), value_2 = c(1, 0, -3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), value = c(-2, 
1, 0), value_2 = c(-2, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), value = c(2, 
0, 0), value_2 = c(-2, 0, -1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```

I want to calculate the mean of the column 'value' for each 'id' across the list. The result should look like this, where 'value_mean' should be the average of the column 'value' of each id in lists 1, 2, 3 and 4.

```
structure(list(id = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), value_mean = c(NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Please note that my real list has 5000 data frames where each data frame has 100,000 rows. I have tried using "bind_rows" and similar functions to convert the list/ to a data frame first, but the data frame becomes too large and R runs out of memory.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may bind the `list` elements to a single data and then use a group by `mean` operation

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst1) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(value_mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id    value_mean
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 id1         0.25
2 id2         0.25
3 id3         0.5
```

---

If the datasets have a the same dimension and the 'id' are in same order, extract the 'value' column, use `Reduce` to do elementwise `+` and divide by the `length` of `list`

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(lst1, `[[`, "value"))/length(lst1)
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.50
```

---

Or a more efficient approach is with `dapply/t_list` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(t_list(dapply(lst1, `[[`, "value")), fmean)
  V1   V2   V3 
0.25 0.25 0.50
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, as my list has 5k data frames, each with 100k rows, this creates a huge data frame with 5000*100,000 rows, and R runs out of memory.

Comment: @xyz Does all the datasets have the same number of rows and id in the same order

Comment: the solution with "Reduce" worked as the ids are in the same order. 

It was super fast too. But dapply has not yet produced anything, maybe just too slow. I will comment if it works. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @xyz maybe it is `t_list` that takes time.  It was supposed to be fast

Answer (score 1):

You could try to calculate the `mean` for each data.frame in your list. Weighted by the elements in each data.frame you could calculate the mean for all data.frames:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_list %>% 
  map_df(~ .x %>% 
           group_by(id) %>% 
           summarise(n = n(),
                     mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(mean_value = sum(n * mean)/ sum(n))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id    mean_value
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 id1         0.25
2 id2         0.25
3 id3         0.5
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm tired right now, don't knwo if this makes any sense.